# Check if there text between different nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to check if there is text between different nodes.

XML:

```
<text>
 Line1<newLine></newLine>
 Line2<newLine></newLine>
 Line3<newLine></newLine><newLine></newLine>
 Line4<newLine></newLine><newLine></newLine>
 Line5<newLine></newLine><newLine></newLine><newLine></newLine>
 Line6<newLine></newLine>
 Line7<newLine></newLine><newLine></newLine><newLine></newLine><newLine></newLine>
</text>
```

My current XSLT is the following:

```
<xsl:template match="newLine">
 <br></br>
</xsl:template>
```

My current output is the following (Ignore the . at the end):

```
Line1
Line2
Line3

Line4

Line5


Line6
Line7



.
```

I want to accept the `newLine` as a tag, and I want it to translate it to `br`, but I DONT want to do this when there's more than two times `<newLine></newLine>`. So I want to accept an empty rule, but not more than one.
Besides that, I also DONT want to have one or more empty rules at the end of the output. So after Line7, nothing may happen.

**Edit:**
To make it a little more clear: If there's `<newLine></newLine><newLine></newLine><newLine></newLine>`, or even more of them, I want to have a maximum of 2 `<br/>` elements

How do I do this?

Comment: So how do you want to transform `<newLine></newLine><newLine></newLine><newLine></newLine>`, into nothing at all, or into a single `<br/>` element?

Comment: @MartinHonnen If there's `<newLine></newLine><newLine></newLine><newLine></newLine>`, or even more of them, I want to have a maximum of 2 `<br/>` elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we restrict the match on

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="newLine[following-sibling::node()[1][normalize-space()]] | 
                     newLine[following-sibling::node()[1][self::newLine[following-sibling::node()[1][normalize-space()]]]]">
  <br/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then for the input

```
<text>
 Line1<newLine></newLine>
 Line2<newLine></newLine>
 Line3<newLine></newLine><newLine></newLine>
 Line4<newLine></newLine><newLine></newLine>
 Line5<newLine></newLine><newLine></newLine><newLine></newLine>
 Line6<newLine></newLine>
 Line7<newLine></newLine><newLine></newLine><newLine></newLine><newLine></newLine>
</text>
```

the result is

```
 Line1<br/>
 Line2<br/>
 Line3<br/><br/>
 Line4<br/><br/>
 Line5<br/><br/>
 Line6<br/>
 Line7
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="text">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::text()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::newLine[1]"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="newLine" >
    <br/>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::node()[1][self::newLine]">
        <br/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```